# Disable GSM calling, SMS, MMS and keep GSM modem enabled?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to disable GSM calling, SMS, MMS and keep GSM modem enabled? I want to use my iPhone without all services except for modem. Thank you for answers!

Comment: Go to your GSM operator and buy a sim card with data access only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, as an developer you do not have access to this part of the system.